# Javascript open new tab/window from a browser and load a different content inside the tab with javascript

Tags: javascript, html, tabs, onclick

I am using a Codeigniter framework. I have a link from a new tab/window from the browser which links my code to the profile of a user. Now I want to load a form from my opened tab which was rendered by javascript. Here is what I've done but it doesn't work.

```
let url = baseurl+'profile/'+applicant_profile_id;
    let tab = window.open(url, '_blank');
    tab.document.getElementById('#container__send_pm').(baseurl+"user/get/message_personal/"+applicant_profile_id, function(){
        $('.pm__msg').click(function(e){                
            e.stopImmediatePropagation();
            $('.spnner__msg_here').html(spiner);
            $('.pm__msg').attr("disabled", true);
            $.ajax({
                url : baseurl+'user/send_message_execute/new_msg',
                type : 'POST',
                data : $('#email_pm').serialize(),
                success : function(response) {
                    if(response == "success") {
                        swal('Message successfully sent', {
                            icon: "success",
                        });
                        $('.spnner__msg_here').html('');
                        $('.pm__msg').attr("disabled", false).val('Send Message');
                        location.reload();  
                    }else {
                        swal('Message was not sent.');
                        $('.spnner__msg_here').html('');
                        $('.pm__msg').attr("disabled", false).val('Send Message');  
                        location.reload();
                    }                       
                }
            });
        });
        return false;
    });
```

As you can see i have an id tag of `#container_send_pm` in my newtab window and i want to load different content from my opened new tab. How can i do something like this?

Comment: Not quite clear what you are needing to accomplish here. Should be able to use user data in session to request whatever you need no?

Comment: @charlietfl i want to change the content of my new tab which i want to render the content with my new tab page like I'm calling a route

Comment: @charlietfl i have a div inside of my new tab and i want to change the content of the said div from my new opened tab

Comment: Lets start with definition of tab.... a new browser window tab or an html/js tab inside current page? Still not clear what is going on and what you need. If it's a browser window tab will need a lot more detail

Comment: a new browser window tab. and in the new browser tab, i want to clear the contents of the div tag id #container__send_pm and render a new content which i stated in the code

Comment: There are a variety of ways to communicate between windows of same app. Best approach would depend on more specific use case and what triggers updates and source of data for updates. Suggest you scale this all down to a very simple [mcve] with more specific details of what you need and how you need the two windows to work together

Comment: @charlietfl i have updated my code that I've posted. hopefully you understand what i want.

Comment: Not really...still far too vague. You might want to research various ways to communicate between windows like postMessage, storage events, serrver side events etc. As an outline to explain it you can't do it with code alone without a more detailed written process flow. What you are wanting to do is not trivial